# CanvasChartJS: how to avoid automatic time interval

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I'm using Canvas column chart with time in X axis.

When I'm updating the time-chart, It is showing the regular time intervals in the chart though there's no data at that time.

This is resulting in a vacancy region in the chart and points at the rightmost end .

```
var liveData=[
    {x:new Date( "Fri Jan 01 1960 " + "10:30:00" + " GMT+0530 (IST)"),
    y: 20},
    {x:new Date( "Fri Jan 01 1960 " + "10:35:00" + " GMT+0530 (IST)"),
    y: 20},
    {x:new Date( "Fri Jan 01 1960 " + "10:40:00" + " GMT+0530 (IST)"),
    y: 20},
     {x:new Date( "Fri Jan 01 1960 " + "11:40:00" + " GMT+0530 (IST)"),
    y: 20}
]

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        width: 820,
                        hieght: 200,
                        title: {
                            text: "Live"
                        },
                        axisX: {
                            valueFormatString: "HH:mm:ss",
                            title: "Time",
                            gridColor: "white",
                            gridThickness: 0,
                            labelFontSize: 13
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            title: "Units"
                        },
                        dataPointMaxWidth: 20,
                        data: [{
                                //                            color: "#B0D0B0",
                                toolTipContent: "Time: {x} <br> Opens: <strong>{y} </strong>",
                                color: "#452323",
                                type: "column",
                                dataPoints: liveData
                            },
                        ]
                    });
```

chart.render();
    http://jsfiddle.net/1ekxfh2w/

I want to see the times only where I've data. How can I achieve this??

Or Any other chart that can do the job for me??

Answer (score 0):

change `x--> label` and it will solve your problem. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishraaj13/1ekxfh2w/3/)